# onWillFocus React Native v6 Replacement?

Tags: react-native

I want to clear errorMessage, when we navigate from Sign in to Sign up and vice-versa, for that I tried using onWillFocus but it has been deprecated.
Can anyone suggest me the replacement of onWillFocus?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the original useEffect hook prescribed which gets triggered when a screen is loaded and when a state changes. You can either pass [] parameters so it only runs once or you can use a state to check it.

```html
useEffect(() => {
    // do you work here
  }, []);
```